# where do I set the password on computer A for file and drive sharing?

Tags: files, password, file-sharing

I am trying to grab some files from my desktop to my laptop.
all seems good. The laptop can see the desktop and the various drives.
BUT when I try to access the drives,  I am being prompted for a password.
I tried my standard password (which I use to logon and Authenticate) but that's not working.
where is that Password set on the computer with the shared drive?

Comment: That depends on *how* the network shares were configured.

Comment: Ask the sysadmin for it... it may be different from your standard password!

Comment: Assuming the server is Ubuntu with samba, you have to use `smbpasswd` on the server to set a samba password for the user to connect. Otherwise, please edit your question with more details on os's and types of shares.